# Git cherrypick for the previous commit

Tags: git

I have a git commit tree something like this,

```
commit1(HEAD->master)
commit2(origin/master)
commit3
```

Now I have to cherrypick a commit from another branch, such that
the commit tree should look like

```
commit1(HEAD->master)
cherrypicked commit
commit2(origin/master)
commit3
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

So you have

```
   ... C ... <--(other_branch)
 /
x ... A <--(origin/master)
       \
        B <--(master)
```

The first thing to do is cherry-pick `C` as you normally would, giving you

```
   ... C ... <--(other_branch)
 /
x ... A <--(origin/master)
       \
        B -- C' <--(master)
```

Then do an interactive rebase

```
git rebase -i origin/master master
```

You'll see a `TODO` list with one line for each commit between `origin/master` and `master`.  Swap the lines for `B` and `C'`, then save and quit.

Answer (score 0):

First create a branch starting from origin/master

```
git checkout origin/master
git checkout -b wip-reordering
```

then using [gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk) cherry-pick visually all items you want in the order you want.

```
gitk --all .
```

you can cherry-pick to current branch using right-click and contextual menu

Check this is wat you want ( if not start again with another branch)

Once you have the wanted configuration, set master branch to head of your new branch

```
git branch -f master
```

The main thing is that during your working phase you are in a branch and you don't impact directly the original work state. Which mean you can try again and again until you have something satisfying.

Clean the wip-** branches.